# Android GPS for a Square region

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I would like to use Androids Gps to as a access point on my app. Meaning if a user isn't with in a square. how do I get Android to accept between (for example: Longitude and Latitude) 50.000 - 65.010 (with 50.00, 50.00 as my Center point or Tower). Now because I want to cover a a 4 block radius how to I get android to accept values only between C to G for both gps values. I guess I want to prevent users from using application outside of city, state, neighborhood ... a square area. So far I am successful in using Gps as a login but I am stuck at hard coded locations:

`if(username.getText().toString().length() > 0 && password.getText().toString().length() > 0 ) {
                    //------------------------------------Username below -------------------------------------Password below ---//
                    if(username.getText().toString().contains("XX.408") && password.getText().toString().contains("-XX.") ) {`

Any input on how I can cover a Square are would be very Thankful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rectange.inside(Point).
Set origin of rectangle to SW corner (x=longitude, y =latitude)
 Set width to longitudinal difference.
Set height to latitudinal difference.